# Node js: run cmd and get the output in error condition

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to get node js to run a cmd command. The problem is, I really want to get the command's output regardless of whether it is a data or an error condition. I am currently using node-cmd to do this job and my code looks like:

```
const cmd = require('node-cmd');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const getAsync = Promise.promisify(cmd.get, { multiArgs: true, context: cmd });

getAsync('sfdx force:source:status --json').then(data => {
    console.log('success');
    console.dir(data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(err.message);
});
```

When the result is success, I am getting the correct data. However, I still want to get the json output from my cli tool when error happens, But in err condition, err.message seem to be a pretty long string. Is there any way I can still retrieve just the data in error condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `|| true` to your command. That will ensure your command will always return success. I'm assuming your server is running on Linux-based OS.

Comment: It is supposed to be cross platform. Is there an alternative for windows?

Comment: Never mind, I have got the answer myself now. Thank you for your suggestion. I will give it a try.